# How to specify that a function returns a certain type when new'ed in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Suppose I have the following third party JavaScript function that I want to call from TypeScript:

```javascript
function foo(obj) {
  var x = new obj.newable();
  x.bar();
}
```

Here is what my JavaScript code (which I want to port to typescript) does:

```javascript
foo({
  newable: function() {
    this.bar = function() {
      console.log("Hi");
    }
  }
});
```

This successfully prints "hi". But now I want to port my code to TypeScript. Especially I want to make sure that the object returned by `new obj.newable()` contains a method `bar`.

I tried some things like:

```typescript
interface IForFoo {
  newable: {new () : IWithBar};
}
interface IWithBar {
  bar: () => void;
}
function foo(obj: IForFoo) { // this will eventually be specified in a .t.ts file
  var x = new obj.newable();
  x.bar();
}
```

but that does not work, because `Type 'new() => IWithBar' requires a construct signature, but type '() => void' lacks one`. (To be honest I haven't figured out what exactly a `construct signature` refers to).

How do I get this "right"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First lets get it to work.

## Working example

The following works and is the simplest solution

```
interface Foo{
    newable:{
        () : {bar:Function}
    }
}

declare function foo(arg:Foo);

foo({
  newable: function() {
    this.bar = function() {
      console.log("Hi");
    }
    return this;
  }
});
```

## Telling TypeScript its newable

If you want to *enforce* the newable constraint i.e it MUST accomodate for `new` you need to use a TypeScript class i.e.

```
interface Foo {
    newable: {
        new (): { bar: Function }
    }
}

declare function foo(arg: Foo);


class NewAble {
    bar = () => console.log('Hi');
}

foo({
    newable: NewAble
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly more convoluted attempt

```
interface IForFoo {
    newable: () => IForBar
}

interface IForBar {
    bar: () => void
}


class Foo implements IForFoo {
    newable(): IForBar {
        return new Bar()
    }
}

class Bar {
    bar() {
        console.log('Hi')
    }
}

function foo(obj: typeof Foo) { // this will eventually be specified in a .t.ts file
    var x = (new obj).newable();
    x.bar();
}

foo(Foo)
```